# I am trying to rotate a div containing nested divs and the div is reflecting vertically?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to rotate this ccs art 360 degrees on mouse hover, but for some reason, the whole div seems to reflect under the origin position. I am fairly new to react and css, so I am honestly not sure why the image vertically flipping when I hover over it

DefaultView.css:

```css
.LilGuy:hover{
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: all 2s ease;
    transform-origin: center center;

}
```

DefaultView.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './DefaultView.css'

export default class DefaultView extends React.Component {


    render(){
        return(
            <div
                style={{
                    height:"100%",
                    width:"100%",
                    position:"absolute",
                    overflow:"hidden"
                }}>
                <div
                    className="bg"
                    style={{
                        background:"radial-gradient(#034FFF,#021645)",
                        position:"relative",
                        width:"100%",
                        height:"100%"
                        }}
                />
                <div className="LilGuy">
                    <div 
                        className="LilDudeOutLine"
                        style={{
                            background:"#FFFF",
                            position:"absolute",
                            width:"510px",
                            height:"510px",
                            top:"50%",
                            left:"50%",
                            transform:"translate(-50%,-50%)",
                            borderRadius:"50px"
                        }}
                    />

                    <div 
                        className="LilDude"
                        style={{
                            background:"#012787",
                            position:"absolute",
                            width:"500px",
                            height:"500px",
                            top:"50%",
                            left:"50%",
                            transform:"translate(-50%,-50%)",
                            borderRadius:"50px"
                        }}
                    />
                    <div 
                        className="eye-left"
                        style={{
                            background:"#034FFF",
                            position:"absolute",
                            width:"75px",
                            height:"75px",
                            top:"40%",
                            left:"44%",
                            transform:"translate(-50%,-50%)",
                            borderRadius:"125px"
                        }}
                    />

                    <div 
                        className="eye-right"
                        style={{
                            background:"#034FFF",
                            position:"absolute",
                            width:"75px",
                            height:"75px",
                            top:"40%",
                            left:"56%",
                            transform:"translate(-50%,-50%)",
                            borderRadius:"125px"
                        }}
                    />
                    <div 
                        className="pupil-left"
                        style={{
                            background:"#FFFF",
                            position:"absolute",
                            width:"28px",
                            height:"30px",
                            top:"38.6%",
                            left:"43.99999999%",
                            transform:"translate(-50%,-50%)",
                            borderRadius:"60px"
                        }}
                    />

                    <div 
                        className="pupil-right"
                        style={{
                            background:"#FFFF",
                            position:"absolute",
                            width:"28px",
                            height:"30px",
                            top:"38.6%",
                            left:"56%",
                            transform:"translate(-50%,-50%)",
                            borderRadius:"60px"
                            }}
                        />

                    <div 
                        className="mouth"
                        style={{
                            background:"#FFFF",
                            position:"absolute",
                            width:"150px",
                            height:"50px",
                            top:"50%",
                            left:"50%",
                            transform:"translate(-50%,-50%)",
                            borderRadius: '10px',
                            borderBottomLeftRadius: '40px',
                            borderBottom: '4px solid #034FFF',
                            borderBottomRightRadius: '40px'

                        }}
                    />
                </div> 

            </div>





        )
    }
}
```

https://gyazo.com/595b80ee2affbf4678d5f6453dd7175f

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did bit of styling and tried with different transform-base numbers, it is more close to what you need. You would still have to try out more set of numbers for transform-origin numbers, the one in .LilGuy:hover class.

here is codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/embed/6vz0nn2x1z

it would still blink if you hover over some part of it because that div has big size and when you hover over in the part of div from where div would be moved on hover, which leads to end a hover effect and try to put div back in place, so in that case it would blink a bit. However you can change the transform-origin numbers I used to fit your need.